# New to junit - how to write test script for method returning a value

Tags: java, android, junit

Here is my java code, it should reverse a string:

```
public String reverse(String str)   {

        String reverse = new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString();

        return reverse;
    }
```

Now here is my JUNIT test code:

```
public class myUnitTest{

    @Test public void test_reverse(){

    assertTrue()    <-- I dont know what I should write

    }
}
```

Apologize for this question to be so basic, but I am really stuck here

Comment: [Documentation on junit assert is here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions)

Answer (score 1):

on account of @Kate Gregory i am giving some explanation below but i thought it would be self explanatory. but while you write a junit for any method in a class you basically use something called Assert statements which let you test your junits efficiently. as for the case below you can use assertEquals(expected result,actual result) for testing your method.

```
public void test_reverse(){
 ClassObject obj = new ClassObject(); --> This should be your class with reverse()
 String reverse = obj.reverse("GOOGLE");
 assertEquals("ELGOOG",reverse);
}
```

Comment: this would be a better answer if you explained why it worked.

Comment: @Kate Gregory as you expected updated my answer with some spice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use assertEquals method to test your returned value equality. It will return true or false test result. First parameter is your expectation, second parameter is your method which returns string.

```
 assertEquals("gnirts ym",reverse("my string"));
```

I think you should some research about jUnit. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html) is a nice starting tutorial.